# CSS border-width of 0px still rendering 1px in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following:

```
.icon {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

The bottom border is set to 0px but in the image below the border is still rendering at 1px. Negative values are obviously not an option.

[image: Border is still appearing.]

Comment: Have you tried setting it to `border-bottom: none;`?

Comment: This problem might be caused because your site is zoomed in or something. This is most likely a rendering problem of the browser, not much you can do there...

Comment: I would just use an image, as this would also support older browsers and shouldnt make any problems

Comment: can you give us a fiddle?

Comment: What version of internet explorer are you using?  Would be useful to visually see what's going on. Also, consider using box-shadow to emulate the desired effect (from the image). It looks like a perfect fit for what you're doing.

Comment: @DavidFariña I screengrabbed the icon and zoomed in on it in photoshop, in the browser the pixels are hardly visible but just enough that I need to remove them.

Comment: @BenjaminSolum using IE 11!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [somethinghere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991619/somethinghere) add a `border-bottom:none` to `.icon` like this:

```
.icon {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Or:

```
.icon{
    border-top: 2px solid #454545;
    border-right: 2px solid #454545;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Please try to see this page in IE and check if the problem is solved.

```css
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.icon{
  border-top: 2px solid #454545;
  border-right: 2px solid #454545;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box icon"></div>
```

Comment: I have tried to set this but it won't apply in IE? Not sure why.

Comment: It is ok in IE11 for me. Whats ur version?

Comment: I'm using IE11 too. I tried to add in the border-bottom property in the developer console and there is no option for just border-bottom, I get options such as border-bottom-color etc.

Comment: I believe u r doing it wrong, as I did a simple html-css test on my client and everything is ok. I will add sinppet to my answer. please check in a minute

Comment: Im can clearly see that you upsized the image to show it here. But is your browser zoom setting at 100%? because it looks like the browser might be zoomed in or out. At least thats something that happened to me often when im not at 100%

Comment: @DavidFariña my browser is set to 100%, I double checked.